# How to use more VRAM?

Tags: customization, gpu, memory-management, settings

I recently bought a graphics card with 12 GB in memory, but when I model complex scenes I see very little amount of VRAM in use, and some times it gets very laggy in the viewport at less than 25% VRAM usage. I don't know why. Is that normal?. Should I find a way to use more VRAM? I think maybe there is something wrong in my Blender's settings or in Windows configuration. I'm using Blender 3.5 and Windows 10, rendering in Cycles with GPU and Optix enabled.  I want to take more advantage of my 12gb of graphics card's memory, if possible.

Answer (score 1):

So, at render time, your computer will take the final version of everything in your scene and package it all up and ship it over to your VRAM, that way your GPU has the fastest possible access to all the information it needs.

Then it just fires away rays and your computer accumulates all that into an image.

Just consider that 12gb the maximum possible scene complexity that you can cram onto your card at render time.

The viewport is taking a lot of shortcuts to get to a very good approximation of the result, and may or may not use vram efficiently, I haven't really looked into it, maybe someone can add to this answer.  In any case I don't think it would be surprising to anyone here for the viewport to run below the desired framerate.

Comment: I don't think this answer is worth a checkmark or anything, I just wanted to ease your feelings on the situation